# Power of a fraction in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate the power of a fraction.

I tryed the code below, but SQL calculates 1/2 as 0 in the power function.

```
Declare @x float = power(4,1/2) 
Select @x
```

It returns 1, while I expected 2.

Does any one knows how to sort it out?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: is this sql-server?

Answer (score 3):

Your database probably does integer division - so `1/2` is `0` rather than `0.5`. You can void this by forcing one number to a decimal, like:

```
declare @x float = power(4, 1.0/2) 
select @x
```

This would return `2`.